# google.load never calls callback

Tags: javascript, callback, load, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to use the Google Earth plug-in, and have found that it's rather particular about how it is called: if called outside the main flow of the Javascript execution (via setTimeout, for example), it simply refuses to call the load callback. The example below is self-contained illustration. Change change which of the last two lines is commented out to see it work or not.

What's going on?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var ge;
      function init() {
        console.log('Initing');
        function cb(instance) {
          ge = instance;
          ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
          console.log('Ok');
        };
        function fail() {}
        google.earth.createInstance('map3d', cb, fail);
      }
      function loadTheMap() {
        google.load("earth", "1.x");
        google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
        console.log('Callback is set');
      }
      //loadTheMap(); // works
      setTimeout(loadTheMap, 200); // Does not work
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map3d" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a timing problem.

`google.setOnLoadCallback()` lets you specify a function that is called when the page loads.

When you use `setTimeout()` like that, it is calling `setOnLoadCallback()` **after** the page has already loaded, so it never calls your function.

Instead of using `google.setOnLoadCallback()` you could do this:

```
  function loadTheMap() {
    google.load("earth", "1.x", {"callback" : init});
    console.log('Callback is set');
  }

  setTimeout(loadTheMap, 200);
```

I'm a little confused though, because the [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/loader/#Dynamic) say that dynamic loading is not supported for Earth, but I've seen [it done in the api samples](https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/source/browse/trunk/demos/dynamic-load/index.html?r=109), and it works for me (in Chrome).