# Google Celendar error when adding a calendar

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, velo

I took this example from Google's API documentation, but when I run it, I get an error. I'm creating a WIX website so I'm using NodeJS:

> google.load is not a function

This is the code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for calendar.calendars.insert
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.calendar.calendars.insert({
      "resource": {
        "summary": "TEMP"
      }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: google.load is not a function when using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090197/typeerror-google-load-is-not-a-function-when-using-ajax)

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ 
 google.load("client:auth2", function() 
 {
  google.auth2.init({client_id: MY_CLIENT_ID)
     .then( (results) => {

     console.log(results);
     }
    )
   .catch( (err) => {
  console.log(err);
   } );
 });
}, 100);       No reponse from the function